# I am trying to use UDP in Qt but packets not recieved

Tags: c++, qt, sockets

I made an application in Qt, in which I will send packets via UDP from a port and receive it in another instance of the same application.
[Image of application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNJeZ.png)

IP and PORT are exchanged on both instances so that it can distinguish between sender and receiver. In one instance I bind and send, and in another instance, I bind and receive.

Here is the code I tried.
When I send the packet using only one address and port it is working fine in one application and console. But when I try to send it on ip2 and port2, it can't receive any data.

myudp.cpp

```
#include "myudp.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "QTimer"

extern myudp Server;
extern MainWindow w;


myudp::myudp(QObject *parent) :QObject(parent)

{

    socket = new QUdpSocket(this);


    //socket->bind(QHostAddress::LocalHost,5678);


    connect(socket,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(readReady()));

}

void myudp::bindfunction(QString ipAdd1, int port1)
{
    QString ipAdd1_1=ipAdd1;
    int port1_1=port1;
    socket->bind((QHostAddress)ipAdd1_1, port1_1);
}



void myudp::WriteData(QString data1,QString address1,int port_1)


{
    QString address1_1=address1;
    int port_1_1=port_1;

    QByteArray data_send;

    data_send.append(data1);

    socket->writeDatagram(data_send,(QHostAddress)address1_1,port_1_1);
    qDebug()<<"Data sent!";


}


void myudp::readReady()

{

    QByteArray buffer;


    buffer.resize(socket->pendingDatagramSize());


    QHostAddress sender;


    quint16 port;


    socket->readDatagram(buffer.data(),buffer.size(),&sender,&port);


    qDebug()<<"Message From: " << sender.toString();


    qDebug()<<"With Port Number " << port;


    qDebug()<<"Message: " << buffer;

}

void myudp::timerfunction()
{
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    timer->start(100);
    connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(readReady()));
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "myudp.h"
#include "stdio.h"

myudp Server;

int port1;
int port2;
//int bindcheck=0;
//int sendcheck=0;
//int value=0;
//int new_value_one;

//QString file;
QString ip1;
QString ip2;
QString data_1;
//QString file_select;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_lineEdit_ip1_editingFinished()
{
    ip1=ui->lineEdit_ip1->text();
}



void MainWindow::on_lineEdit_port1_editingFinished()
{
    port1=ui->lineEdit_port1->text().toInt();
}

void MainWindow::on_lineEdit_data_editingFinished()
{
    data_1=ui->lineEdit_data->text();
    ui->label_output->setText(data_1);
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_bind_clicked()
{
    Server.bindfunction(ip1,port1);
}


void MainWindow::on_pushButton_recieve_clicked()
{
   Server.timerfunction();
}

void MainWindow::on_lineEdit_ip2_editingFinished()
{
    ip2=ui->lineEdit_ip2->text();
}

void MainWindow::on_lineEdit_port2_editingFinished()
{
    port2=ui->lineEdit_port2->text().toInt();
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_send_clicked()
{
    Server.WriteData(data_1,ip2,port2);
}
```

Comment: Why are you copying the parameters of your functions? You are passing by value, so you already have a local copy anyway. Also you are not supposed to call your `readyRead()` slot with a timer, it is already connected to the `readyRead()` signal of the `QUdpSocket`. Regarding your UDP issue, do you have any error/warning from Qt at run-time in the console output? Did you checked with a tool like wireshark if the UDP packet is sent? Does `bind()` return `true` or `false`? Did you check the `QAbstractSocket::error()` signal?

Comment: Bind() returns true. After altering the code a bit, now it's kind of working. The program runs fine after one unsuccessful pass. But it sends data to another instance's console right after I hit send in 1st instance, i.e. without even hitting receive in other instance. I think readReady() gets executed right away. I tried connecting it to receive button's click slot but it's not working.

Comment: That's normal. QUdpSocket will emit `readyRead()` as soon as it is notified by the operating system that new data is available. You do not need to do any action. Please read Qt documentation and pay extra attention to the event loop. Understanding it is key to proper network programming in Qt.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I made all changes and now the app is working fine, as per my requirements. I'll post working code if anyone needs.